# WC_Structured_Data Class Causing Needless Translation

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, translation, seo

I am using the Weglot plugin to translate our Woocommerce site. Weglot allows you to exclude areas that you don’t want translated, to save from your quota of words.

Weglot says:

*Excluded Blocks
By default, everything is translated on a page but you can exclude a section of a page by entering the CSS selector or HTML block you want to exclude.*

We have successfully blocked everything containing the product name/product title EXCEPT one thing. There is a script running that contains the product name/product title and Weglot is translating the data in the script, even though it is not displayed. I have been working with Weglot support for about a week trying to figure out how to exclude it, but nothing has worked.

Based on what Weglot said about, about excluding page sections, can you figure out a way to make the script able to be excluded? What is that script for and, if it isn’t important, is there a way to remove it or the product name/product title that it is pulling?

Here is the script from the page. The translated words are: “Diamentowy wisiorek” (originally “Diamond Pendant“)

```
> <script
> type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"https:\/\/schema.org\/","@graph":[{"@context":"https:\/\/schema.org\/","@type":"BreadcrumbList","itemListElement":[{"@type":"ListItem","position":1,"item":{"name":"Strona
> g\u0142\u00f3wna","@id":"https:\/\/store.dolina.org"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":2,"item":{"name":"Christmas
> Ornaments (Bombki
> Choinkowe)","@id":"https:\/\/store.dolina.org\/product-category\/christmas-ornaments-bombki-choinkowe\/"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":3,"item":{"name":"Diamentowy
> wisiorek","@id":"https:\/\/store.dolina.org\/product\/diamond-pendant\/"}}]},{"@context":"https:\/\/schema.org\/","@type":"Product","@id":"https:\/\/store.dolina.org\/product\/diamond-pendant\/#product","name":"Diamentowy
> wisiorek","url":"https:\/\/store.dolina.org\/product\/diamond-pendant\/","description":"Kr\u00f3tki
> opis","image":"https:\/\/store.dolina.org\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/02\/jewelry.jpg","sku":213,"offers":[{"@type":"Offer","price":"250.00","priceValidUntil":"2021-12-31","priceSpecification":{"price":"250.00","priceCurrency":"USD","valueAddedTaxIncluded":"false"},"priceCurrency":"USD","availability":"http:\/\/schema.org\/InStock","url":"https:\/\/store.dolina.org\/product\/diamond-pendant\/","seller":{"@type":"Organization","name":"Sklep
> wysy\u0142kowy Zespo\u0142u Pie\u015bni i Ta\u0144ca
> Dolina","url":"https:\/\/store.dolina.org"}}],"aggregateRating":{"@type":"AggregateRating","ratingValue":"4.00","reviewCount":1},"review":[{"@type":"Review","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":"5","ratingValue":"4","worstRating":"1"},"author":{"@type":"Person","name":"storesklep"},"reviewBody":"This
> is a test","datePublished":"2020-08-03T14:50:53-06:00"}]}]}</script>
```

I even tried adding  around where I thought the scripts were being pulled in footer.php.

```
   </div> <!-- Page end -->
   <div id="No-Translate-Scripts">
   <?php wp_footer(); ?>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

So far, I have only noticed it on the product page.  A programmer said the script is for  WC_Structured_Data Class.  Any thoughts about where the script is coming from or how to get it excluded?    Weglot support had me add the following code snippet, but it didn't work:

```
add_filter( 'weglot_add_json_keys',  'custom_weglot_add_json_keys' );
function custom_weglot_add_json_keys(  $keys  ){ 
    $keys  =  array('desc');
    return $keys;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the line number 103 in the file /weglot/vendor/weglot/weglot-php/src/Parser/Check/RegexCheckerProvider.php

original code :

```
/* Add JSON LD checker */
    $this->addChecker(new RegexChecker("#<script type=('|\")application\/ld\+json('|\")([^\>]+?)?>(.*?)<\/script>#s" , SourceType::SOURCE_JSON, 4 , array( "description" ,  "name" , "headline" , "articleSection"  )));
```

To replace by :

```
/* Add JSON LD checker */
    $this->addChecker(new RegexChecker("#<script type=('|\")application\/ld\+json('|\")([^\>]+?)?>(.*?)<\/script>#s" , SourceType::SOURCE_JSON, 4 , array( "description" , "headline" , "articleSection"  )));
```

You must use FTP to make this change because this file is in a vendor folder.

Best

Comment: Merci!   Just for clarification, I'll need to download the file via cPanel, edit it, and then send it back to the folder?      (Sorry, I'm a trial and error person who has no coding / web training.   Just naturally techie.)

Comment: Merci!   Ok, I went into cPanel, made a backup copy of the file and then replaced the line you suggested.  It worked until I clicked on the "Reviews" tab (Translated as "Recenzja").  When I did that and reloaded the translated page, it translated it again. :(

Comment: I tried with another browser and it translated it even without click on the reviews tab, so that might have just been a coincidence.